# A connection was successfully established with the server, An Error Occurred During The Pre-Login Handshake in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a Scheduler Task Console Application in ASP.NET Core 6. The local environment service is working as expected, but not when it is deployed to the production server.

It worked fine when the Job was executed the first time. After that when the job is running I get the following error. The application is scheduled in JAMS Job Schedular.

Exception Details: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.), StackTrace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

I have added **;TrustServerCertificate=true** in the connection string. Find the following connection string.

"Data Source=myTest;Initial Catalog=testDB;persist security info=True;User Id=testuser;Password=testPwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=true"

I'm having the same problem/issue.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support TLS 1.2. Update SQL Server **or configure TLS/SSL settings in the docker image/client environment to connect with TLS 1.0.** 
Modify /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf. It will contain following:

    ...
    [system_default_sect]
    MinProtocol = TLSv1
    CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#possible-reasons-and-solutions

Answer (score 0):

I tried and solved the issue by adding the following to the connection string.

**;MultiSubnetFailover=True;TrustServerCertificate=True**

"Data Source=myTest;Initial Catalog=testDB;persist security info=True;User Id=testuser;Password=testPwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;MultiSubnetFailover=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"